# Is there any way to manipulate folder permissions from apex code?

Tags: apex

Is there any way to manipulate folder permissions from apex code.Let’s say some folders are not visible to some user or group but based on some other conditional changes now they need access to those folders so, how can we automate it from apex code instead of system admin manual intervention.

Answer (score 0):

I think using the access type field in Folder object we can implement the same.

Comment: You can change the accessType to either hidden, public or shared. But I dont think you can add the public group/ role that the folder should be shared to.. The API doesn’t allow you to view, insert, or update which group or Role the Folder is shared with. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_folder.htm#topic-title

Comment: @theGreatDanton that seems to be an answer in it's own right - you should post it as one.

Answer (score -2):

You can assign permission sets from apex:
https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_permissionset.htm
https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_permissionsetassignment.htm